# Better way to do this Servlet/bean pass tablename from servlet to bean class in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have bunch of products close to 100, and each product has its own table in DB,for this I have implemented search feature for each product,now I was thinking of reusing the code since other than few parameters and table names rest logic all remains same,

String test = request.getParameter("test");

test is dropdown list which contains information about products,

the way I was thinking of is

```
if ( test.equals(ProductA)) {
          List<searchbean> list = dao.fetchDBRecords(tableA,other parameters of form);
        }
```

parameters from the list are passed to sql query.

Now my question is ,does it makes sense to use a single class for multiple products or it makes more sense to have seperate class for each product.

I am asking this for 2 reasons, over the period of time,my code base seems to have increased a lot(300+ classes) and I need a way to control it from further growing.How is this often dealt with?.
If I go with single classes for mulitple products, will I be hitting any concurrency issue which I need to take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you do not create a SQL injection problem by taking a parameter from the request and injecting into a query.
2. You should use the same class for all products. If some products have additional features, use a property map (preferred), or use inheritance to derive subproducts from the main product class.
3. You do not have any concurrency issues from using one class for all products. You only have concurrency issues from using an instance of a class (not a class but an instance of a class) from multiple threads.
4. The way you are doing it, you would have over 300 comparaisons (if (parameter.equals(product1){...}). A more general way is to prepopulate a hash map and look up values using the parameter  as the key:

   Map<String, String> tableNameMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
   tableNameMap.put("param1","table1");
   tableNameMap.put("param2","table2");

   String paramValue=request.getParameter("test");
   String tableName=tableNameMap.get(paramValue);

Comment: Thanks Tony,Let me refactor it and create a map for it.Also can you elaborate more more on property map of your pt no 2.Pt 1 I will take care and point 3 is what I was thinking of.Maybe I need test this and see how it goes.

Comment: I just implemented your suggestions, and now I dont need to have close to 100 if then statements.Thanks Tony.

Comment: property map: Rather than use table columns for additional attributes, create table properties(object_id, name, value). In java it is Map<String, String> of properties, for example ("color", "red"). ("width", "2.5"), etc...

Comment: I did the same thing,but my bad, I have table per product with table definition different for each product.So so I cannot reuse the DAO class.Maybe Duffy was right,at times design issues are real painfull.Generic table definition could have saved a lot,but it involves tradeoff in terms of business and extensibilty.Maybe slowly I will fix this issue.For now its up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the "class per product" or "table per product" model.  You shouldn't have to modify your code every time you add or remove a product.  You will have to think about the problem a bit abstractly, but it'll be worth it as long as you don't go too far and make an unrecognizable mess.

You'll always have to worry about concurrency issues, but I think that's true for either design.

You have 300+ classes and you're going to add more?  And you're worried about *concurrency*?  Certainly concurrency is important, but you've got to tame your design first.

Comment: if i understand the question properly, cant we just implement inheritence in this case ?? . like having a super product class with some command behavior and make other products to extend that ??

Comment: You can do it that way, but it still means creating a new subclass when you add a product.  I think it's easy to imagine a generic Product class and backing schema that would work just fine.

Comment: yes, but what if all the products dont share same behaviour ?? how would you implement that in one class.. i am just curious  :)

Comment: I'm sure they don't have the same behavior when they get into the hands of the customers, but as far as the kinds of systems that they appear in for commerce they behave exactly the same: inventory, purchase, ordering, shipping, etc.  You don't believe that Amazon has a new table for every product, do you?

Comment: I am not sure if Amazon has new table for every product but yes if we share a table and have generic table for all products, then obviously we are creating kind of dependency down the line and it chokes the future growth and can create an issue whenever we want to add extra features to those products,of course there are ways wherein we can always a create a bridge table and link it to the main table.But this approach has an risk that might spillover  to other products.

Comment: Duffy, thats whole purpose of my question, taming the design and ensuring it remains within control,as of now I have written the code, which does the work what its suppose to do and still I have to implement around 70% of the functionalites and then there whole bunch of UI refactoring I need to do to customise each product.Let me experiment with my design approach.Maybe I can reduce couple of classess for some of my pending modules.

Comment: You're whistling in the dark, Kiran.  "Dependency"?  My opinion is that you've got worlds of trouble that eliminating a couple of classes won't fix.  Feel free to ignore this advice, but you'll be the one feeling more and more pain as time goes by.

Comment: Duffy,maybe you are right,but again unless I experiment and get some results its hard to comment.My objective was have some better way of doing things,tony did have some good suggestion, and I am implementing it,testing it.If it works great,else come back here and start another thread.:)

Comment: Also I never knew that in stack exchange ,people can come together  to close the question,just because its question can spark debate or is not supported by facts etc etc.I like it,maybe next time I will ask something which will meet your guidelines.Thanks everyone.Appreciate and understand your compulsions.

Comment: duffy, you are going personal friend.I agree that I have to learn a lot about design.But again let me tell you something, I have as much experiences serving the communities as any of the founders of stackexchange has or any of the moderators here has, its just that I come from different profession and thats reason I come here.

Comment: Secondly for anyone who helps or gives reply to my question, I often thank them sincerely, I dont know how to vote in SO nor I believe in votes or would advise any moderators here or else where to accept anything other than vote of thanks.I will definitely give credit to people who has helped me doing things better.I may be slow but I know I will surely come to the speed shortly and will be as good as any of the experts here.

Comment: Feel free to ignore any of my questions Duffy.